# jms order of message delivery with high availability

Tags: jms, weblogic, high-availability

I have set up uniform distributed queue with weblogic server 12c. I am trying to achieve order of delivery and high availability with jms distributed queue. In my prototpe testing deployment I have two managed servers in the cluster, let us say managed_server1 and managed_server2. Each of this managed server hosts jms server namely jms server1 and jms server2. I have configured the jms servers with jdbc persistent store. I have enabled server affinity.

1. I have a producer running such as  java queuproducer t3::/managed_server1. I send out 4 messages. From the weblogic monitoring console I see there are 4 messages in the queu since there are no consumers to the queue yet.
2. Now I shut down managed_server1.
3. Bring up a consumer to listen on java queuconsumer t3://managed_server2. This consumer cannot consume message since the producer send all the messages to jms server1, and it is down.
4. Bring up managed server 1, start a consumer to listen to t3://managed_server1 I can get all messages.

Here is my problem say if the managed_server1 went down then there it never came back up, do  i loose all my messages. Also if there is another producer sending messages to java queuproducer t3://managed_server2 then order of messages based on the time between these producers are not guanranteed.

I am a little lost, am I  missing something. Can unit of order help me to overcome this. Or should I use distributed topic instead of distributed queue, where all the jms server will receive all the messages from producers, but if one jms server where my consumre is listening fails there is only one consumer in my application, when I switch over to other jms server, I might be starting to get messages from the beginning not from where I left off.

Any suggestions regarding the same will be helpful.

Comment: Can you confirm that you're using a single JMS connection factory?

Comment: Yes it does use one jms connection factory.

Answer (score 2):

Good Question !

" Here is my problem say if the managed_server1 went down then there it never came back up, do i loose all my messages. "

Ans - no you do not loose all your messages, they are stored in the JDBC store configured for the JMS server deployed on managed server 1. If you want the Messages sent to managed_server1 to be consumed from managed_server2 you need to configure JMS migration.

" Also if there is another producer sending messages to java queuproducer t3://managed_server2 then order of messages based on the time between these producers are not guanranteed.  Can unit of order help me to overcome this."

Ans - If you want the messages to be consumed strictly in a certain order, then you will have to make use of unit of order (UOO). when messages are sent using UOO, they are sent to one of the several UDQ destinations, if midway that destination fails, and migration is enabled the messages are migrated to the next UDQ destination and new UDQ messages are also delivered to the new destination.

Useful links -

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B9J7q5NbXag
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_W3EJ8p35lI

Hope this helps.

Comment: SridharS thanks so much for your answere, this was something I was really looking for. Will try out automatic service migration along with UOO implemented I should be good.

Comment: This is indeed how WLS works when UOO and JMS migration are enabled. Note however that the migration time is not insignificant and may be on the order of "minutes" when there are thousands of messages in UOO queue. Further, other WLS resources are NOT necessarily coordinated with the migration. As a result, message consumers can attempt to read from the migrated queue BEFORE it is migrated, resulting in JMS Connection/QueueSession errors (repeatedly) until the migration completes.